# How to display a Powerpoint presentation within a Delphi App on computers without MS Powerpoint?

Tags: delphi, powerpoint, vcl

I would like to build a self contained Delphi application that includes the ability to display a series of powepoint presentations without requiring the end user to have MS Powerpoint or the MS Powerpoint viewer installed on their machine.

I'd like to know two things:

1. Is this possible?
2. What vcl components are availabe to make this happen?

**Update:**

Microsoft PowerPoint allows the user to save presentations as a Windows Media Video (.wmv). There are several components that allow you to play back .wmv files in Delphi. This is how I solved the challenge using Delphi.

Comment: You don't require the user to have viewer installed, but it's not clear to me if your application is allowed to install it or not?

Comment: How many lines of code do you consider "possible"?  I'd say it's possible, in about a million to a million and a half lines of code. And there are no components that do this.

Comment: Have you thought about converting the slides to a PDF format?  Probably won't be able to include all the bells and whistles possible in Powerpoint...

Comment: @Gunny: Typically, questions that ask "is it possible" are considered extremely vague and not answerable. You really should be much more specific; as it's phrased now, an acceptable answer would be "Yes, and there are no vcl components available" or "No, and there are no vcl components available". Since those obviously aren't useful answers, perhaps you should rephrase your question.

Comment: [OpenOffice Impress](http://www.openoffice.org/product/impress.html) can open Powerpoint files and convert them to Flash. With Delphi it's possible to view Flash animations, [Running Flash animations with Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/graphics/l/aa040103a.htm).

Comment: I don't really see why there are votes to close this question. I think it is valid (although one should not use the Asperger interpretation of the first question, and the second should read 'are there any...' instead of 'what vcl...').

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1 - This should be possible if your application duplicates the functionality of MS PowerPoint viewer. PowerPoint Presentation file format specification is [available from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313106%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

2 - There are no special purpose VCL components for this task.

Comment: Well, one should probably also point out that doing (1) yourself is a HUGE undertaking.

Comment: #1 is like saying "Sure, you can build a new car without buying any third party parts. First, find a bunch of scrap metal...".

Comment: @Andreas - Yeah, I didn't mean to make it sound simple. I thought, duplicating the functionality would imply basically writing the viewer all over again. It would appear I was wrong though...

Comment: The basic question was "Is this possible" and not "Is this simple" or "Is this wise" or "Can I handle this". Following the link OP can prove if simple or wise for him. Generalized questions forces generalized answers. BTW my answer to "Build a new car ...?" would be just rolling eyes.

Comment: @SirRufo: And your point is? The basic question was meaningless (almost everything is *possible*, including building a car out of scrap metal). "Is it practical?" is another question entirely. :-) It's *possible* to write your own Office Suite using the documentation specifications from MS, so you don't need to buy Office at all. Is it practical to do so? Only if you have years to waste and your time is worth less to you than the cost of buying the Office license. (IMO, the question shouldn't have been answered, because it was too vague. I didn't downvote Sertac's answer, though.)

Comment: @Ken The question got the answer it deserved. But you are right. "Can I build a rocket and fly to the moon?" Sure you can. Will you? Not so much. A far better question would be to present the goals and ask for suggestions on how to meet those goals in a tractable manner. I up vote Sertac, and down vote the question.

Comment: @David, I think the question's title phrases it best. The two body questions aren't so good. The first is a boring yes/no question, which we can see leads to unhelpful answers. The second is OK, but limits solutions to components, when there could be other products that can help work with the documents that aren't Delphi components. Like, maybe the viewer application can be redistributed and comes with an embeddable COM object. Or maybe the ppt format happens to be easy to display manually.

Comment: @Rob - I don't see how this answer is unhelpful. In my view this question is not obscure in any way. The answer to the title in the question could be answered by suggesting MS's viewer or a possible 3rd party viewer. But the body explains the question more so that these possibilities are barred. I don't see anything wrong with any of these. FWIW, unfortunately MS's viewer does not offer automation, the last one that did was the 2000 viewer and it required at least running once on its own to have it registered, it also required either the existence of office suite or its runtime to be present.

Comment: Your answer is essentially that anything is possible because it's all just software; we can write anything we want to. Your *comment* is more helpful because it explains more about why the easier solution ideas won't work. You only mentioned them because I did, though, not because the question asked. The question didn't necessarily say the viewer couldn't be installed by the application, just that the computer didn't already have it. But you didn't have to addressee that possibility anyway because the question never asked *how* to display files, just whether it was possible to do at all.

Comment: @Rob - I see your point. But it maybe that the possibilities you're talking about does not interest the OP at all, so it still may not be a bad question - only the OP knows it. And I slightly disagree that the answer is analogous with anything is possible, it would be more like it if we didn't have the format spec. :)